# How to get data immediately on Slave instance after inserted on Master instance when using MySQL Replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 2 MySQL version 5.7.23 and InnoDB instance: Master (write) and Slave (only Read)
When I run the source code to insert to Master, but at this time, when call query to get data on Slave instance, the data have not updated yet.
Then I checked this updated on Slave, this data is existed in both Master and Slave by debug on source code.

Then I checked as following case:

1. Use single DB Master >> I got the data from Slave
2. Use Replicate DB:  Master + Master >> I got the data too.
3. Use Replicate DB, Master + Slave >> it is problem. I have not data.

On MySQL Replication, it is no cached query setting. The Seconds_Behind_Master is 0 value.

Could you tell me how to detect and how to fix this issue?
Many thanks...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and show the source code you are using to save to the DB and retrieve the data. If you are trying to read the data from the slave at the same time as you are saving it to master, there may a bit if a delay depending on several factors.

Comment: MySQL Version 5.7.23, DB is InnoDB version.